# How does SVD of homogeneous system of equation with embedded RHS make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

In the following article, section **3.1** authors use SVD to solve overdetermined system of linear equations:

http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklth/personal/solem/publications/Solem-Heyden-ICPR2004.pdf

The idea behind using **SVD** is clear, but the confusing part is that the system has been made homogeneous by embedding right hand side vector into the system matrix $M$. This means that the unknown vector $v$ has a known constant as an element.

$$
  \underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
      -1
    & {}
    & {}
    & \mathbf{p}_{1x}
    & \mathbf{L}_{1x}
    & {}
    & \cdots
    \\
      {}
    & -1
    & {}
    & \mathbf{p}_{1y}
    & \mathbf{L}_{1y}
    & {}
    & \cdots
    \\
      {}
    & {}
    & -1
    & \mathbf{p}_{1z}
    & \mathbf{L}_{1z}
    & {}
    & \cdots
    \\
      -1
    & {}
    & {}
    & \mathbf{p}_{2x}
    & {}
    & \mathbf{L}_{2x}
    & \cdots
    \\
      {}
    & -1
    & {}
    & \mathbf{p}_{2y}
    & {}
    & \mathbf{L}_{2y}
    & \cdots
    \\
      {}
    & {}
    & -1
    & \mathbf{p}_{2z}
    & {}
    & \mathbf{L}_{2z}
    & \cdots
    \\
      \vdots
    & \vdots
    & \vdots
    & \vdots
    & {}
    & {}
    & \ddots
  \end{bmatrix}
  }_{M}
  \underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{X}^l_x \\
    \mathbf{X}^l_y \\
    \mathbf{X}^l_z \\
    1 \\
    \mu_1 \\
    \mu_2 \\
    \vdots
  \end{bmatrix}
  }_{\mathbf{v}}
  = 0
$$

How does it make sense to do SVD of such Matrix?

Comment: It appears that they're using the SVD to find a basis for the null space of the matrix and then finding a vector in the null space which has that particular element equal to one.  You might edit your question to include the homogeneous system of equations and explain clearly any special constraints on the solution.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for the reply. As far as I understood the authors are doing SVD in order to get the least squares solution of the overdetermined system. It is not mentioned that there are constraints to the solution. Therefore I assume that least squares solution is obtained by taking the column of the $V$ matrix that corresponds to the smallest singular value. Anyway would it be the same if we would remove column with $p_i$ entries in matrix $M$ and  solve least squares problem with right hand side that is consisted of $p_i$ entries ?

Comment: "The equations can be written as Mv = 0, where the elements in M and v are ...  The solution is found as the nullspace of the matrix M. This is obtained using a singular value decomposition (SVD)."  makes it clear that they're using the SVD to find a basis for the null space of M.